# How to disable Emacs highlighting whitespace in parenthesis?

Tags: emacs, whitespace, parentheses

[image]

In the above screenshot, it can be seen that Emacs highlights the whitespace between parentheses, unless I move my cursor one place to either side.

I have smartparens enabled in my emacs config, but even if I disable them, this problem still persists. 
I also don't have whitespace-mode enabled.

Any idea what may be causing this?

The relevant part of my config:

```
(require 'smartparens-config)
(smartparens-global-mode t)
(show-smartparens-global-mode t)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior w/ `smartparens`, what other modes do you have active (type `C-h m`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately the solution given by **Ignacy Moryc**, didn't help me, but this one helped:

```
(setq sp-highlight-pair-overlay nil)
```

Comment: Wow, didn't expect to find a solution for this after so long, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This looks like `show-paren-mode`

If you have `(show-paren-mode t)` anywhere in your config file, you might want to remove it. Or you can change the `show-paren-style` variable value to `parenthesis`

```
(setq show-paren-style 'parenthesis)
```

Comment: Resp. M-x customize-variable RET show-paren-style RET

Comment: With Show Smartparens Mode, you'll likely want to disable Show Paren Mode.